# Unfortunately stopped this app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 3 buttons on my screen (Restart, Previous, Next) and a 1 imageView.
no error show by android studio in java and xml. then why this app not working

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/i1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="407dp"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:src="@drawable/i1" />

   <Button android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prev"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Res"
        android:id="@+id/restart"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my java code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener { 

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i1);
Button next;

int a = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart);
    restart.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    previous.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.restart:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i1);
            a = 0;
            break;

        case R.id.next:
            if (a == 0)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i2);
                a = 1;
            }
            else if (a == 1)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3);
                a = 2;
            }
            else if (a == 2)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i4);
                a = 3;
            }
            else if (a == 3)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i5);
                a = 4;
            }
            else if (a == 4)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i6);
                a = 5;
            }
            else if (a == 5)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i7);
                a = 6;
            }
            else if (a == 6)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i8);
                a = 7;
            }
            else if (a == 7)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.i9);
                image.setClickable(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.previous:
            a--;
            next.performClick();
            break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Initilize and move  your imageview bellow the setConentView() method.Declare it as global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          Button next; 
          int a = 1;
          ImageView image;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i1);
            next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
            next.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart);
            restart.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
            previous.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

Comment: previous button not work as i need.. its only work last to second last image return.... i want previous button work as a previous button in each stage of app

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i1);
```

should come after

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

in onCreate method

App is crashing because of NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Why the image is initialized out of the onCreate()? do it in onCreate() method right after setContentView()